# why html tags are not working inside servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets, httpresponse

I'm new to Servlets I just trying to print a simple Html tag inside servlet response but I dunno why it doesn't print in Browser. it just print the String without getting the Html tags.

Here is the code:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Hi All");
        PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h2>Please complete our Customer Survey</h2>");

    }

}
```

**Out Put print as **

```
<h2>Please complete our Customer Survey</h2>
```

Please let me know how to fix this 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ContentType must be set.
Try this.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Hi All");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h2>Please complete our Customer Survey</h2>");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, mate it works thanks a lot. also, i think this happens because Java 8 on older versions we should not need to setcontenttype

Comment: @atiqkhaled it works but in programming there can be many ways to do that's y I kept silence. i'm looking for more answers